# Using UPDATE and JOIN in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have to do a project based on a timeline (just the back office of the timeline). 
So I have two entity :

```
 - DateTL : ID, DAY, MONTH, YEAR
 - Timeline : ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION and DATETIMELINE
```

Datetimeline is :

```
 @OneToMany
 private List<DateTL> datetimeline
```

In my DB, Netbeans do 3 tables : **DateTL**, **Timeline** and **Timeline_DateTL** (with rows TIMELINE_ID and DATETIMELINE_ID)

Now I try to attach date in my table DATETL to TIMELINE. I try with :

```
update Timeline_datetl SET timeline_id = :timeline_id, datetimeline_id = :datetimeline_id
```

But I have an error (The abstract schema type 'Timeline_datetl' is unknown.)
So I try :

```
update Timeline t SET t.datetimeline = :datetimeline_id where exist (select d from DateTL)
```

But don't work too and i don't know where put timeline_id

Thank for your help !

Comment: What is the name of the `entity` of `Timeline_datetl`? P.S. it is easier just to merge the objects instead of writing your own update statements

Comment: It's just a table create automatically by Netbeans. I dont have a entity for Timeline_datetl and it's my problem because I dont know how update this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL you select/update/delete Entities. A join table is not usable as the candidate. If you want to update the contents of the join table then you update the RELATIONS that it represents via the objects.

Comment: So how update my table Timeline_dateTL ? Via Timeline ?

Comment: I already said, via the objects of the Entities that form the relation. Not via a bulk "UPDATE" query (which is not what a BULK update is for).